# .load not working, I think I have the concept wrong?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have read the documentation and some online resources for the .load() method, and for the app I am building it is not working. Please note I have never had to use .load before.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#next').click(function(e){
    alert("Click"); // this alerts when clicked as expected
    $('#atestimonial').load('testimonial.php', function() {
        alert('Load was performed.');
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

The event works as intended. That code block is in header.php (using wordpress) and the actual div #atestimonial is in sidebar.php, **so it is in different files; does this matter?**

Inside of testimonial.php  is this:

```
<?php 
include('testimonialPull.php');
echo "Bahh";
?>
```

testimonialPull.php

```
<?php
require_once('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
    query_posts(array(
        'cat' => 4,
        'order' => 'ASC', // ASC
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'showposts' => 1,
    ));
    $wp_query->is_archive = true; $wp_query->is_home = false;
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content();
    endwhile; endif;
?>
```

If i remove the contents of testimonialPull, then it echos correctly.

Which just gets a random post into the atestimonial div.

The structure of the actual div and button is this:

```
<div id="testimonials">

<div class="tHeading"><h4>Client Testimonials</h4></div>

<div class="atestimonial">
    <?php
    include('testimonial.php');
?>
</div>
<div id="next"><a id="nextC" href="#" return="false">NEXT TESTIMONIAL</a></div><!-- END #next -->

</div><!-- END #testimonials -->
```

So, have I done something wrong for the testimonial to not show in the div with the .load?

Thank you for taking time to read this.

**FAST EDIT**

This is working on localhost; I have just read that this does not work with localhost, is this  correct?

Comment: First, check if your .load returns any data at all. Secondly, check your jQuery – in you load function, you don't do anything with the returned data (if there is anything returned).

Comment: You trying to load content to a `div` with `id="atestimonial"` which is not exists on your page.

Comment: Your jQuery selects `#atestimonial` while in your html your div has a class of `.atestimonial`, not id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking jQuery to fill `$('#atestimonial')`, that is an element whose id is `atestimonial` but you don't have such element in your page.

Replace

```
<div class="atestimonial">
```

by

```
<div id="atestimonial">
```

**EDIT :**

by reading your comments I think you may have a path problem, depending on where you include your script.

Instead of

```
$('#atestimonial').load('testimonial.php', function() {
```

You may need something like

```
$('#atestimonial').load('/testimonial.php', function() {
```

or

```
$('#atestimonial').load('/ggg/testimonial.php', function() {
```

Comment: Oh my.. Another thing which I missed, thank you! I cannot believe I missed that! (I will mark as correct when it lets me)

Comment: What do you precisely mean by " its not bringing any data in from the file now" ? if you're trying to read in javascript the content of the injected content, you must have a consistent domain.

Comment: The wordpress stuff in the testimonial.php file should output a string, however nothing is being returned from the .load

Comment: I don't see any `echo` in your php code. Is it in `the_content();` ? You should open the "network" tab in the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) to check what's answered by the server.

Comment: Its saying this, GET http://localhost/ggg/wp-content/themes/ggg/testimonial.php 404 (Not Found) however, if i remove all the wordpress stuff to make it display the post it echos correct (see revised OP). Also, after removing wordpress code, the 404 error disappears

Comment: I'm not sure about your "localhost" question. There may be many problems (other domain, other app name, missing files, bad php configuration, etc.).